# How can I pass parameter when upload image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, closures

My javascript code is like this :

```
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {        
    $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageProducIsLoadedt;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        } 
    });
 }

function imageProducIsLoadedt(e) {
    $('#thumbnail-view-0').attr('src', e.target.result);
    document.getElementById("thumbnail-upload-0").style.display = "none"
    ...
};
```

For example  I click input file with name = photo-3, it will run loop on the index 3

Which I ask is : How do I send parameter i = 3 to imageProducIsLoadedt function?

I try add parameter like this :

```
reader.onload = imageProducIsLoadedt(e, i);
```

And the imageProducIsLoadedt like this :

```
function imageProducIsLoadedt(e,i) {
```

But, there exist error like this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

I try to update global variable like this :

```
let test = '';
for(let i=0; i < 5; i++) {        
    $('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').change(function () {
        test = i;
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageProducIsLoadedt;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        } 
    });
 }

function imageProducIsLoadedt(e) {
    console.log(test)
    ...
};
```

It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function with register onload and inside that call your imageProducIsLoadedt function like below

```
   for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {        
$('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').change(function (e) {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        (function(i){
         reader.onload = function(){
           imageProducIsLoadedt(e,i);
         }
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    } 
  });
 }
```

Comment: Lol, I was about to answer with a hack involving setting the value on a new property on `reader`, then access it via `e.target.photoId`, but then saw your answer and remembered this is Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, funny Javascript, no strict way of doing stuff.

Comment: @Gaurav Pandvia, It's the same. I try : `reader.onload = function(){
                    imageProducIsLoadedt(e,i);
                }` and `function imageProducIsLoadedt(e,i) {`

Comment: The param 'e' is missing , in change function try this way , `$('input[name="photo-'+i+'"]').change(function (e) { ... }`

Comment: @Gaurav Pandvia, I had add it. But e undefined

Comment: @Gaurav Pandvia, I had find answer. You try see my question. I had update it. I using global variable. And then I update it when a index clicked

Comment: @samueltoh  But that is not ideal, putting the variable in global scope unless it is a closure. See this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vftue1y8/43/) , I have created in which I am able to get both 'e' and 'i' inside function foo()

Comment: @GauravPandvia actually does `reader.onload = function(e) { imageProducIsLoadedt(e,i); }` need to be encapsulated? `(function (i) { reader.onload = function(e) { imageProducIsLoadedt(e,i); })(i);` otherwise won't `i` always be the last index?

Comment: @Flosculus Yeah you are right, since on load is asynchronous , the value of i depend on the stack call, so by encapsulating we might be able to store its value. I forgot that  thing...

Comment: @Gaurav Pandvia, Great. Thanks. Seems I will follow your step